# QMainWindow mouseDoubleClickEvent override not working

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside6

I'm using the below code to try and capture double clicks within the main window"

```py
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QSplitter,
    QTreeView,
    QWidget,
)
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.windowLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.splitter = QSplitter()

        self.webView = QWebEngineView()
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8080"))
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.webView)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self.mainWidget = QWidget()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.windowLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        print('test')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(1500, 1000)
    window.show()

    app.exec()
```

And I get the following console output:

```
qt.pointer.dispatch: delivering touch release to same window QWindow(0x0) not QWidgetWindow(0x600003bb8e40, name="MainWindowClassWindow")
qt.pointer.dispatch: skipping QEventPoint(id=1 ts=0 pos=0,0 scn=749.346,451.159 gbl=749.346,451.159 Released ellipse=(1x1 ∡ 0) vel=0,0 press=-749.346,-451.159 last=-749.346,-451.159 Δ 749.346,451.159) : no target window
```

however, when I comment out `self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)` I obviously don't see anything, but the double click triggers. Any suggestions?

EDIT: update to min repro, also note that clicking anywhere not inside the QWebEngineView correctly results in `mouseDoubleClickEvent` triggering. However, the above error results when I click in the `QWebEngineView`, and nothing happens when I click inside the `QTreeView`

Comment: This seems more like a Qt issue, and I cannot reproduce it on PyQt6 (I cannot test it on PySide6 right now) on Linux. What OS are you using? What Qt version? Are you just creating a QApplication? With or without arguments? Please provide a *complete* [mre] so that we can ensure that you're not doing anything else.

Comment: I have tested it on Linux with PyQt6 and PySide6 and it works correctly, I don't see what you indicate. Could you give more details of your environment? for example OS, version of PySide6 or PyQt6, version of python, etc.

Comment: MacOS 12, PySide6.2.4, VSCode, editing original post with min repro

Comment: @eyllanesc, updated with min repro and more details of behavior at bottom, apologies for the incomplete original post

Comment: @joshp those messages are probably from the QtWebEngine (and possibly related to macOS). Besides any widget that handles mouse events will *not* propagate them to the parent, so, they could be probably ignored. The real question, though, is: are you trying to catch double click events *on the web view*? To what purpose?

Comment: @musicamante I'm trying actually to catch double click events on `QTreeView`, so that I can identify the item that was clicked and perform an action accordingly. Is there anyway to propagate to `QMainWindow` so I don't have to pass the object I'm operating on all the way down the `PyQt` object chain? e.g. something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47963920/12728698

Comment: @joshp Why don't you just use the [`doubleClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked) signal?

Comment: @musicamante I can do that, but then I need to pass the object (e.g. `currentFilePath`) that I want to modify down, I.e. `MainWindow -> TreeContainer -> FileTree` where the double click event information is, and I'm anticipating more layers in the UI potentially as the complexity grows. Thus, I was hoping to make the call at the top level. Perhaps I'm imagining it wrong?

Comment: @joshp If you want to add "more layers", then *you* are adding complexity, but that doesn't mean that it's bad. The "downside" of OOP modularity is that it *might* make things a bit more complex, but that's expected. You could add an event filter as in the link above, but that's an option that should only be used when no other alternative exists (or because you need specific or extremely controlled behavior). `doubleClicked` already provides the clicked index, and you can access its information by a simple `index.data()`, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @joshp Besides, the point remains: events that are handled and accepted by a widget (when the widget's `event()` returns `True` for those events) are ***never*** propagated to the parent, so there's no other way: you either use signals, or you use an event filter. Remember that event filters will always go through **all** events an object would receive, and in the case of item views that could happen very frequently (views normally update even on mouse movements): adding that overhead for something that the class already provides seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 0):

As per musicamante's very useful comments (see original post), the solution I ended up using was

```py
...
     self.tree.doubleClicked.connect(self.treeDoubleClicked)
...
def treeDoubleClicked(self, index):
     self.selectedFilepath = index.model().filePath(index)
```